SharePoint Subscription Edition search service application does not create crawled properties for custom site columns
We installed SharePoint Subscription Edition on Windows Server 2022.
The Frontend and application servers are running on Windows Server 2022 and the Search servers on Windows Server 2019 (due to an issue on 2022).
We created the search service application and indexed a web application with a site collection with custom content types and custom site columns. After the full crawl is done, the crawled properties corresponding to the custom columns are not created.
Just to be clear, there is content with these custom columns and values in them.
We tried with custom columns deployed via a .wsp solution but also with custom columns and content type created via the browser in the site settings page.
We checked in the search SQL database in the crawled properties table and the properties are not there either.
What could be the cause for this? How can we trace the issue?
